# Apollo-react SSR not return data, but return loading: true

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-apollo, apollo-client

Good day. I have problems with the server rendering of the application, in conjunction with the Apollo-React. The request goes to the server, but the layout only returns a stub for loading: true. How should it work? I do not receive data. I use an example from the official documentation. Nothing happens.
Here is the code for server rendering.

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: true,
    link: createHttpLink({
        uri: 'MY_API',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            cookie: req.header('Cookie'),
        },
        fetch,
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const Module = (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <SearchModule/>
    </ApolloProvider>
);

renderToStringWithData(Module).then(async (content) => {
    const initialState = await client.extract();
    const html = <Html content={content} state={initialState} />;

    res.status(200).send(renderToStaticMarkup(html));
});
```

Here is the code for the component itself.

```js
const query = gql`
  query {
    Smilies(get_all: true) {
      smiley_id
    }
  }
`;

const SearchModule = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(query, {
    ssr: true,
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
  });

  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
          return <h1>{key}</h1>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <h1>Loading!</h1>;
  }
};

export default SearchModule;
```

Comment: Hi. There isn't enough information for me to help you. What example did you try? Are you getting any errors (in server or browser console)?

Comment: @ChickenSoup, Added code from the project